# Angular using html2canvas and waiting until its completed (async / await?)

Tags: angular, async-await, angular12

I have an issue where I need to run 2 methods in a specific order, waiting for the first one to complete before running the second one.

Here are these 2 sample methods:

```
part1() {
  const element = document.getElementById("capture") as HTMLCanvasElement;
  html2canvas(element).then((canvas) => {
    this.thecanvas = canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log('Dont do part2 until the.thecanvas is populated');
  });
}


part2() {
  // do other stuff but only after part1 is completed
  console.log('All completed');
}
```

I'm running them like this:

```
main() {
    // I need them to run in this sequence
    this.part(); // first
    this.part2(); // last
}
```

I'm guessing I should use `async/await` ?

How do I do this in Angular 12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `async/await`. This is how you change your code:

```
part1() {
  const element = document.getElementById("capture") as HTMLCanvasElement;

  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const canvas  = await html2canvas(element)
        this.thecanvas = canvas.toDataURL();
        console.log('Dont do part2 until the.thecanvas is populated');
        // when you complete the things successfully, you shoule call resolve else call reject
        resolve('Dont do part2 until the.thecanvas is populated'); 
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
      
  })
 
}

part2() {
  // do other stuff but only after part1 is completed

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('All completed'); 
      // when you complete the things successfully, you shoule call resolve else call reject
      resolve('All completed');
  })
  
}
```

You can always follow these steps when you have something async in nature. You can create a promise and you can `resolve/reject` it based on the results.